# Why is my Android AdapterView not working after moving it to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapterview

I am working on an app that reads data from a database, and displays it in a ListView. This was working well until I moved my code from the MainActivity.java to a fragment. Now, not so much. I don't get any errors, but the list does not populate like when the code was in the main activity. This is what I had **before** fragments:

**data_view.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_linear_layout">

        <include layout="@layout/table_header" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/row_of_stats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**from MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        dataCursor = myDBHelper.getDataCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"time", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.time_textview, R.id.col1_textview, R.id.col2_textview, R.id.col3_textview, R.id.col4_textview, R.id.col5_textview};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_data_row_layout, dataCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.row_of_stats);
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);
}
```

Now, this is what my new fragment looks like, that does not work:

```
package mypackage.main;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import mypackage.R;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private Cursor dataCursor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_view, container, false);

        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        dataCursor = myDBHelper.getDataCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"time", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.time_textview, R.id.col1_textview, R.id.col2_textview, R.id.col3_textview, R.id.col4_textview, R.id.col5_textview};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.my_data_row_layout, dataCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.row_of_stats);
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

Like I said, the AdapterView worked perfectly, and showed the list of data, but now it is just empty with no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are infalting your layout twice.
Change :

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_view, container, false);
```

to

```
return rootView;
```

Comment: That's fantastic, it worked perfectly. Thank you. So, where am I inflating my layout other than in the actual return statement?

Comment: You are inflating the layout here :
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_view, container, false); 
And you are using this view to find your listview etc.
So everything is fine, but at the end, you inflate the layout again and return this new inflated layout to the container.

Comment: Ah, Ok, I see it now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Brian you if the answer solved your issue please validate it.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin If you mean "accept the answer" I plan on doing this. StackOverflow is making me wait 10 minutes before I can. Thank you.